# Usage of inherited button subclass with a click-event-method and its syntax in python tkinter

Tags: python, inheritance, events, button, tkinter

The program aims to finally become a calculator where the Entry box displays the letter/number which the button represents. There is always the brute force way of defining every button's parameters. I want a customized button class that has certain properties defined so that I don't need to redefine for every button. So I inherit the Button class to make a subclass. I decide to put the click-event-method inside the class which is shown below. But it seems to throw an error when I click the button when the main window is displayed. Can you please help me figure out what is wrong. The complete code is below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")
myFont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=19, weight='bold')

e = tk.Entry(root, width = 20,font=myFont)
e.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4)

class calc_button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self["height"]=1
        self["width"]=6
        self["font"]=myFont
    def ClickMe(self):
        print(f'The text is {self["text"]} ')


button1 = calc_button(root,text="1",command=calc_button.ClickMe)
button1.grid(row=4,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Error is as shown below :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\subramaniantr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: ClickMe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: You can call the bind function inside `__init__()` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `command=calc_button.ClickMe` you're calling the method on a *class*, not an *instance* of the class. You need to be creating an instance.

Since you're using a class so that you don't need to redefine the same property for every instance, you can define the `command` method inside the `__init__`, like so:

```
class calc_button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self["command"]=self.ClickMe
```

If you wish to define the `command` outside of the `__init__`, like you are currently trying to do, it will require two steps since you can't reference the button before it is created:

```
button1 = calc_button(root,text="1")
button1.configure(,command=button1.ClickMe)
```

---

Unrelated to the question being asked, your code will be easier for others to comprehend if you stick to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming standards. For example, class names should always begin with an uppercase, and function names should always begin with a lowercase.

Comment: Thank you. The first solution seems to be very elegant. I'm new to python and tkinter is a corona aided skill. So not yet there with PEP8 standards. But will keep this in my mind. thanks.